# Server rendering React app behind a URL prefix with react-router

Tags: javascript, nginx, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router, React 0.14 and nginx to render a universal JS app. Because I'm in the middle of transitioning an existing app, I need to put the new 'react' code behind a url prefix, say `/foo`

However, I'd ideally like nginx config to handle the `proxy_pass` to the react server running on a local port (say 8080).

nginx conf

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

React-router `routes.jsx`

```
import HomePage from 'components/pages/HomePage';
import AboutPage from 'components/pages/AboutPage';
import NotFoundPage from 'components/pages/NotFoundPage';

export default (
    <Route path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route path="*" status={404} component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Route>
);
```

Nothing special on the server. The server-side rendering seems to work fine, but when it gets to the client, since the path doesn't match up it shows the following Warning in the console:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) <div class="NotFoundPage" data-r
 (server) <div class="HomePage" data-react
```

Which I guess makes sense since the URL is actually `http://localhost:80801/foo` instead of `http://localhost:8081/` which react-router is expecting on the client.

Any ideas of ways around this other than putting the `/foo` prefix in the top-level Route? The reason I don't want to do that is I don't want to have `/foo` prefixes everywhere (in the `<Link />` components for example).

MTIA!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure a `baseURL` when [setting up the history object](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/d4aa590dd13848a857ca27508149552458c7cdfb/examples/dynamic-segments/app.js).

```
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'

const history = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/foo'
})
```

Comment: `useBaseName` is removed from `history` v4, FYI for anyone in the future.

Comment: try   <BrowserRouter basename='/foo'>