# Trouble hosting react app at location using docker nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, server

I've been stuck on this for over a week now and its driving me bonkers haha. Essentially I have a react app I created for a client that wants it to display at `clientdomain.com/react-app`. I'm using docker to spin up a container that's running at `localhost:8000`. When I visit localhost:8000/react-app the project displays properly as I have the app routing there using react-router. Unfortunately when visiting the target url and path it's blank and has a few of these errors in console; `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://clientdomain.com/static/js/2.f5d5b027.chunk.js”`

here is the nginx config for the clients site with the location config i've added at `location /react-app`

```
     server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        server_name clientdomain.com www.clientdomain.com;

        root /var/www/clientdomain;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        rewrite ^/artiklar/([^/]+)/$ /article-$1.php last;



     location /react-app/ {
            rewrite ^/react-app/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
   }
```

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:11 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

FROM mhart/alpine-node
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

Also this is the `/var/www/html` folder structure

```
/var/www/html
/var/www/clientsdomain
/var/www/react-app
```

Ive also tried to use just `serve -s build` and remote proxy to the localhost it is being served at but the same issue occurs.

These are the docker commands that are being used as well to build and run

```
docker build -t react-app .
docker run -it -p 8000:80 react-app
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the root URL of the react app when running locally? `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8000/react-app`?

Comment: its localhost:8000 but react router displays at /react-app. Sorry ill add a bit to clear that up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this : [Server rendering React app behind a URL prefix with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164103/server-rendering-react-app-behind-a-url-prefix-with-react-router)

You should run react app with prefix:

```
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'

const history = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/react-app'
})
```

AND:

You are rewriting `/react-app/` to `/`

You should remove rewrite :

Remove this line :  `rewrite ^/react-app/(.*)$ /$1 break;`

Comment: I removed that and still the same issue:/

Comment: how did you access `clientdomain.com/react-app/` ? it  works ?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm unsure what you mean by access.

Comment: I meant  It works when you access  `clientdomain.com/react-app/` (you see react app index page on that link ?)

Comment: ahh in console under sources it's accessing a folder react-app that contains an incorrect index.html file and not the correct folder that contains the build files